# Jquery .get() - How to pass the value of a text box into the data parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is one form with a `textbox id="name"` and a button.

After the user clicks the button, I want to execute the `$.get()` to capture the reply. (I got the .click() correctly so far)

How to I pass the value the user enters to the text box as the {data} parameter in the get function?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like:

```
$('.button_class').click(function(){
  var val = $('#name').val();

  $.get('example.php', {name: val}, function(data) {
   alert(data);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$.get("user_clicked_handler.php", { name: $("#name").val() },
   function(data){
     alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
   });
```

Calling $("#name").val() returns value of input box.

Answer (score 2):

[This Stack Overflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295095/how-do-i-set-a-textboxs-value-using-an-anchor-with-jquery) was the first thing that came up on Google.

jQuery has [a page about the `val()` method](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

The data is stored in `$("input#name").val();`